# Visual Studio Advanced Installer Extension - how to package app.config files in console app

Tags: visual-studio, advanced-installer

I am using the Advanced installer extension in Visual Studio 2019 to package a console application.  It works fine except that it does not package/install any of the .config files (such as myexe.exe.config).

Does anyone know how to get it to do this?   The console application has transforms using SlowCheetah and on build places them correctly into the bin// directory.

I would expect these files to be listed as 'primary content' and exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add (one-time operation) the .config file in your setup project using the [Edit in Advanced Installer] button. Have a look on their [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/xG3RpCOtv4c?t=73).

Comment: sorry for the delay in replying. That tutorial seems to be for something different - it uses an external advanced installer project - but doesn't mention web transforms at all.